# Why does an AVL tree of height h has a min number of node = F(h+2) - 1

Tags: recursion, fibonacci, avl-tree

**Question:** Why does an AVL tree of height h has a min number of node = F(h+2) - 1, where F(h) is the h*th* Fibonacci number?

I know that a recurrence for the min number of nodes in an AVL tree with height h can be written as: N(h) = N(h-1) + N(h-2) + 1

I would like to know why N(h) = F(h+2) - 1. Do I have to solve both recurrences explicitly and plug in the numbers, **or is there any other way of seeing it, since the form of N(h) = N(h-1) + N(h-2) + 1 is extremely similar to that of the Fibonacci sequence, so I assume there would be another way of doing it directly from from the Fibonacci sequence.**

Answer (score 0):

I provide a more extensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367981/what-is-the-minimum-sized-avl-tree-where-a-deletion-causes-2-rotations/14035092#14035092), but this occurs because a Fibonacci tree is the sparest tree you can have before the AVL algorithm invokes a rotation and reduces the height of the tree.

Comment: Hmmm yes, I think I understand what you mean. But that is a bit complicated for me at the moment. Also, I was actually looking for a more mathematical approach to the question.